# SSL Certificate Validation Azure

Tags: azure, validation, ssl

I registered my domain on Azure and purchased a certificate through Azure.

I successfully stored the certificate in a vault.

I cannot get past the verification It is supposed to verify automatically since both the domain registration and the SSL purchase were done through Azure.

I tried getting it to send me an verification email, but that errored out.

Answer (score 0):

This may cause by Azure could not identify your domain owner information. I will suggest that you could partially disclose your domain owner information so Azure could find the domain owner and verify this domain for you. You also could select the manual domain verification method.

Additionally, If you don’t see your domain validated within an hour, you could [open a support ticket.](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) Feel free to let me know if you still have a question.